# How do I show a custom module settings page as tab of another existing settings page?

Tags: 8, navigation

I am developing a custom module for Drupal 8.0.1 which shows a custom form in *admin/config/people/ban/settings*.

*admin/config/people/ban* is the routes used by the Ban module. *admin/config/people/ban/settings* should be shown as *Settings* tab in that route, while the settings for the Ban module are shown in the *Default* tab.

How can I achieve this in my module?

Answer (score 3):

You need a local tasks menu link yml file, see example in node module: [node.links.task.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!node.links.task.yml)

Comment: This is my module.links.menu.yml file

Comment: Can you provide a working example?

Answer (score 3):

For this you need to create a route in the module.routing.yml file

```
route_name:
  path: 'admin/config/people/ban/settings'
  defaults: 
    _form: '\Drupal\modulename\Form\FormController'
    -title: Form Title
  requirements:
    _permission: 'your permission string'
```

then you need to create another yml file with the name mymodule.links.menu.yml

add the following code

```
form_config_link:
  title: Configure Form Title
  description: 'Configuration Form description'
  parent: system.admin_config_people
  route_name: route_name //defined above
```

You need to check system module yml file for parent name

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that always need at least *two* local tasks for local tasks to show up. They don't do if there's only one.

So, define a `yourmodule.menu.task.yml` and put two definitions in there. Default, which has the existing ban route for both base_route and route_name and yours, which has your route_name and the same base_route as the the default task.

What used to be the default task in Drupal 7 is now simply the task that has base_route == route_name.